# Always reinstalling packages

Tags: r, rstudio

I just need to solve a problem with my RStudio. I have the lastest version on both R & RStudio, but every time that I reboot the PC ad open the program it tells me that some packages are not installed. After several times I have noticed that the problematic packages are: stringi, MASS, survival or Rcpp.

Also if I have to install another package which depends on them a warning appears saying that the packages mentioned are not updated, and it gives me the option to update all.

I tried to reinstall them and enter as an admin in RStudio but nothing works so, does anyone know what is happening here? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

R packages are installed into libraries. The location of libraries searched by R is determined by the value of `.libPaths()`. Likely you have the problematic packages installed in more than one library; check for the same package installed in both `dir(.libPaths()[1])` and `dir(.libPaths()[2])`, for instance.

Use `remove.packages()` with the `lib=` argument to remove one installation.

My practice is to install R and *base packages only* in the default library (possibly as administrator), and to install all other packages in a library that I as a regular user have access to. The personal library is the first entry in `.libPaths()`, which is the default location for package installation. See `?.libPaths` for how to set up libraries; all library paths have to exist, else R silently drops them from `.libPaths()`. I use a setting in `~/.Renviron`. Thus

```
> .libPaths()
[1] "/home/mtmorgan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5-Bioc-3.8"  # personal
[2] "/home/mtmorgan/bin/R-3-5-branch/library"                    # base
> sapply(.libPaths(), function(path) length(dir(path)))
/home/mtmorgan/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.5-Bioc-3.8 
                                                      236 
                  /home/mtmorgan/bin/R-3-5-branch/library 
                                                       30
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! it was painful to reinstall the packages all the time.

Comment: Regarding OP's question "but every time that I reboot the PC ad open the program it tells me that some packages are not installed", why would that happen if the package is installed in more than one library?